# Detecting capacitive touch in low power applications

Tags: capacitor, arm, capacitance

Using some kind of ARM, the application has a very low profile of about 30-50uA .
I would like to detect capacitive touch. If I do this with code, I will have to wake and sample, and thats expensive for a coin cell.

Is there a clever way to create some hardware with MOSFet that will create an interrupt to the ARM so the touch will not be in code ?

Yes we can close some mosfet with some gate configuration , but then how would you do double tap and all other things that can be done only by code sampling ?

Answer (score 1):

Use 1uA opamp to amplify the 60Hz, convert to rectified 120Hz, filter with LPF and use 1uA comparator to detect the strong input, then trigger a WAKEUP for the ARM.

Comment: Thanks, as I said, this solution is far from being good, you loose the first few ms, hence your code can't do things such as gesture recognition because it looses time.

Comment: Then stimulate with 2,000Hz tone; your response time ---- still with amplify/full-wave-rectify/cross-threshold now is 250uS.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a companion chip like the [MSP430FR2663](http://www.ti.com/product/msp430fr2633?qgpn=msp430fr2633)?  It claims 1.7uA per capacitive button scanning when it's in standby mode and less than 0.9uA per button in Wake-on-Touch mode.  It has a little hardware block that can do this without waking up the processor.  Then you can wake up and do all the gesture detection you want and then go back to sleep.